# Time conversion to Epoch seconds

Tags: matlab, epoch

Is there a way to convert  time= `08/10/2014  23:34:02` to Epoch seconds (array of numbers) in MATLAB?

Comment: wait, you want Epoch seconds right?

Comment: yes i want epoch seconds.

Comment: What format is the date/time now? A string?

Comment: @hbaderts yes it is a string now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want the Unix standard which can be calculated as follows:

```
InputDate=datenum('20141008 233402','yyyymmdd HHMMSS');
UnixOrigin=datenum('19700101 000000','yyyymmdd HHMMSS');

EpochSecond=round((InputDate-UnixOrigin)*86400);

>> 1412811242
```

EDIT for the OP's date format:

```
MYSTRING = '08/10/2014 23:34:02';
InputDate = datenum(MYSTRING,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
UnixOrigin=datenum('19700101 000000','yyyymmdd HHMMSS'); %//This can stay the same, unless you want to change it for consistency.
EpochSecond=round((InputDate-UnixOrigin)*86400);

>>1412811242
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you just explain me how to convert "08/10/2014  23:34:02" to '20141008 233402' as you have used in your answer?

Comment: @Bob, it is the yyyymmdd format, which means 2014 is the yyyy (year in 4 digit), 10 (October - I am in the UK and this is how date is represented) and 08 (8th day).

Comment: could you just tell me how to convert the "08/10/2014 23:34:02" strings to 'yyyymmdd HHMMSS' format in matlab? Actually i have a lot of them for the conversion...

Comment: @Bob you want to use datenum to convert your dates to Matlab date numbers. so if your string says MYSTRING = '08/10/2014 23:34:02' you can use datenum(MYSTRING,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS') which should translate it into the correct date number